# Flutter slider value is not update inside getx dialog

Tags: flutter, slider, flutter-getx

I am trying to build a slider widget inside a dialog. I am using [GetX](https://github.com/jonataslaw/getx), and a GetxController but the value of the slider or any other widget is not updating when I am trying to change it.

It only updates after I reopen the dialog. This is my code for the controller:

```
class SliderController extends GetxController {
  static SliderController get to => Get.find();

  var quality = 0.0.obs;

  void setQuality(double quality) {
    quality.value = quality;
    update();
  }
}
```

and my widget looks like this:

```
class SliderWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  const SliderWidget ({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Opacity(
      opacity: 0.8,
      child: GetBuilder<SliderController>(
        init: SliderController(),
        builder: (ctrl) => Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white70,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16)),
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.25),
                spreadRadius: 2,
                blurRadius: 2,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                right: 0,
                top: 0,
                child: CustomCheckBox(
                  value: false,
                  shouldShowBorder: true,
                  borderColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  checkedFillColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  borderRadius: 8,
                  borderWidth: 2,
                  checkBoxSize: 22,
                  onChanged: (checked) {
                    if (checked) {
                      Get.defaultDialog(
                        textConfirm: "Save",
                        textCancel: "Cancel",
                        content: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text("Quality (${ctrl.quality})"),
                            Slider(
                              value: ctrl.quality.value,
                              min: 0,
                              max: 100,
                              divisions: 100,
                              onChanged: (double value) {
                                ctrl.setQuality(value);
                              },
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ]
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

So, the dialog opens, I try to drag the slider around but it doesn't change. Seems like the value is saved in the controller because if I close the dialog and open it again, the slider has the new values.

I don't know how to make the controller update the value inside the dialog's slider

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am seeing you are using the wrong combination. In this case you are using observables (`.obs`) in the controller, but using `GetBuilder` in the widget.
Keep in mind that `GetX` or `Obx` is used to observe the observables (Reactive State Management). `GetBuilder` is used for simple state management (Non-reactive/Non-observables).

So you can either change your variable type as normal dart types instead of Rx (.obs) in your controller like:

```
class SliderController extends GetxController {
  static SliderController get to => Get.find();

  double quality = 0.0;

  void setQuality(double quality) {
  this.quality = quality;
  update();
 }
}
```

Or you can use `GetX` or `Obx` in you widget. In that case no need to call `update()` on the controller.

Comment: Thanks. That made me go back to the docs and understand better these concepts. Now it works